# tikz graph with edges skipping "generation"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tree with three levels and want to draw edges from level 1 to level 3.
I am using the "edge from parent" but would like to use something like "edge to grandparent".
The result I got so far has a Y-shape which os ok'ish, though I'd prefer two straight lines to the "grandparent".

Any way to get a "grandparent" option in there?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amstext}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=60mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=35mm,set style={{every node}+=[circle]}]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=20mm,set style={{every node}+=[circle]}]

\node{}[grow'=south]
child {node{$\overline{G}$}
    child{node[label={right:}]{$\overline{A}$}
        child{node[label={right:}]{$\overline{E}$}
                edge from parent        
                node[ right,draw=none,fill=none]{~$1$}
            }
            edge from parent        
            node[ right,draw=none,fill=none]{~$0.35$}
        }
    child{node[label={right:}]{$A$}
        child{node[label={right:}]{$\overline{E}$}
                edge from parent        
                node[ right,draw=none,fill=none]{~$0.7$}
            }
        child{node[label={right:}]{E}
                edge from parent        
                node[ left,draw=none,fill=none]{$0.3$~~}
            }
            edge from parent        
            node[ left,draw=none,fill=none]{$0.65$~~}
        }   
    edge from parent        
    node[above right,draw=none,fill=none]{$0.87$}
}
child {node[label={}]{$G$}
    child{
            child{node[label={below:}]{$\overline{E}$}
                    edge from parent        
                    node[ right,draw=none,fill=none]{~$0.996$}
                }
            child{node[label={right:}]{$E$}
                    edge from parent        
                    node[ left,draw=none,fill=none]{$0.004$~~}
                }
                edge from parent
                %node[ left,draw=none,fill=none]{$0.65$~~}
            }   
        edge from parent        
    node[above left,draw=none,fill=none]{$0.13$}
}
;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: working example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for comparison, here is the tree using `forest`, which provides the `tier` option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw, circle, inner sep=1pt, l sep=7mm, s sep=1cm,
    if n children=0{tier=leaf}{}
}
[
    [$G$, edge label={node[midway, above left]{0.13}}
        [$E$, edge label={node[midway, left]{0.004}}]
        [$\overline{E}$, edge label={node[midway, right]{0.996}}]
    ]
    [$\overline{G}$, edge label={node[midway, above right]{0.87}}
        [$A$, edge label={node[midway, left]{0.65}}
            [$E$, edge label={node[midway, left]{0.3}}]
            [$\overline{E}$, edge label={node[midway, right]{0.7}}]
        ]
        [$\overline{A}$, edge label={node[midway, right]{.35}}
            [$\overline{E}$, edge label={node[midway, right]{1}}]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that's the way I like it =]

Now I have to fix the forest.sty as there seems to be "an extra }" somewhere and updating the repository did not fix this =(

Comment: solved the problem with the "forest.sty": 
there seems to be a conflict when using 
\usepackage{german} and 
\usepackage{forest}

switched to \usepackage[german]{babel}